# Why does xCode move my objects around?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, layout

I have a scroll view that I am using to accommodate for landscape mode (because I can't lock portrait mode), in that when the user rotates, they are still able to scroll through the menu.

The image below was made to show what I mean, what I actually want is for the grey 'Sponsors' box to be pinned to the bottom of the page regardless of orientation of screen size.

[image: Correct Layout]

This is what I get when I run the app with the above layout
[image: Run App]

For some reason it just shifts the box down. Attached below is my current constraint setup and the code I have to size the scroll view, just to help you.
[image: Constraints]

Code

[image: Code]

By the way the view controller you see in the pictures is a child to a navigation controller and a tab bar controller. P.S. I am NOT using Autolayout, I have tried this and for some reason it makes all my table contents disappear as well as do some other weird stuff, so I stuck away from it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In storyboards, select your sponsors box, then go to 'Editor' -> 'Pin' and select the one most appropriate. You likely will be pinning the bottom space to the superview.

Comment: Oh sorry, I should have clarified I am not using Autolayout as that REALY stuffs things up.

Is there an alternative.

Comment: Are you testing on a 3.5 inch screen and laying out your view on the 4" storyboard?

Comment: everything is being done in the 4 inch layout, e.g. the storyboard is set to 4 inch and I am running the app in 4 inch.